# Change text-decoration of value in column with column validation

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, calculated-column

I need the word Received to have a line through it and waiting for as it is.

[image]

```
="<DIV style='text-decoration:"&IF([Status]="Received","line-through","none"))&";'></DIV>"
```

The above code does not work. Is my syntax word or is it not doable? Also I don't have designer.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to assign different css classes to the divs that have received as opposed to waiting for.

You could then map your text-decoration to the div class.

So your conditional if/then statement would be based off where the decision is made as to where it is received or waiting.

```
<style> .received {text-decoration: line-through; } </style>

<div id="I assume your code is identifying this" class="received">Received</div>
```